# SVD on Banachspaces?

Tags: continuity, operator-theory, banach-spaces, spectral-theory

Let T be an compact, positiv, linear operator on any hilbert space. I know from the SVD that there exists some eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ and eigenfunctions $\phi_i$ such that

$$
Tf=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\lambda_i\langle f, \phi_i \rangle \phi_i.
$$

So i can use spectral properties as $||T^r||\leq \max_i{\lambda_i^r} $ and moreover since T is positiv $||(I-T)^r||\leq (1 - \max_i{\lambda_i})^r $ for any integer $r > 0$ if $\max_i{\lambda_i^r}<1$.

Now I need to do the same for an operator $T:C\rightarrow C$, where C denotes the space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$.

More precisely let K be a bounded continous positiv kernel $|K(x,y)|< 1$ and consider the integral operator $$T:C\rightarrow C; Tf=\int_{\mathbb{[0,1]}} K(.,y)f(y)dy.$$

Is there any way to bound $$\sup_{||f||_{\infty}<1}||(I-T)^r f||_\infty<1$$
or maybe
$$
\sup_{||f||_{\infty}<1}||(I-T)^r f||_{L^2[0,1]}<1 \,\,\,???
$$

Comment: You don't say what $C$ is. Also, you cannot expect your bounds to not depend on the norm of $f$ (the way they are written, both sups you wrote are equal to infinity, unless $(I-T)^r=0$). 

There is also the issue of what $(I-T)^r$ means for $r$ not an integer.

Comment: Thank you! i've corrected it.

Comment: Also, in the Hilbert case you consider $1-T^r$ while in $C$ you ask about $(1-T)^r$. Which is which?

Comment: It should be $\|1-T^r\| \leq 1 - \min \lambda_i^r$

Comment: Damn it haha. Thank you.